# PowerShell Script to evaluate CIS Benchmark Output file and perform non compliant operation automatically

Tags: powershell, automation

Is there a way to semi automate the evaluation of CIS Benchmark against a Windows .
PowerShell script to fetch the CIS Benchmark result file and evaluate against the CIS standards.
If we find any non compliant result in file ,It should automatically perform the specific non compliant operation and revert the settings back to CIS Standards

Can we do this with the help of PowerShell Script?